# Create Database within the same Cluster without closing active connection?

Tags: postgresql, python

Is there  a way to clone a master database without closing an active connection? I have a single **master** database and multiple **slave** database. To clone a new database I use the following command

```
CREATE DATABASE slave_n WITH TEMPLATE master
```

This command is very nice but it is giving me trouble. I have to currently close any active transaction to the master database. This cannot happen because I am using a loop in python and the command is on the loop. E.g. of my code:

```
con = connect(dbname='postgres', user=user, host='localhost', password=password)                                                          
con.set_isolation_level(ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT)                                                                                       
cur = con.cursor()                                                                                                                        
for db in self.browse(ids):                                                                                                               
    if db.created:                                                                                                                        
        continue                                                                                                                          
    dbname = db.name                                                                                                                      
    cur.execute("select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='"+master_db+"'"); ##terminate active connection    
    ## select pg_terminate_backend(procpid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='db'; ###falback if psql <9.2                             
    cur.execute('CREATE DATABASE ' + dbname +" WITH TEMPLATE "+master_db)                                                                 
    '''                                                                                                                                   
    database.set_active_db(master_db)                                                                                                     
    db_con = database.get_connection()                                                                                                    
    db_con.execute("update report_template set created = True")                                                                           
    db_con.commit()                                                                                                                       
    '''                                                                                                                                   
cur.close()                                                                                                                               
con.close()
```

Is there a way to clone without having to delete all the connection? My first code `con = Connect` is also closed Resulting in unwanted errors.

Any suggestion or Help is highly appreciated.

Comment: "*Is there a way to clone without having to delete all the connection?*" - no, there is no such way